# jQuery chaining .load() requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, chaining

So I was working with jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) just now and it looks like we can't configure `$("#example").load('./uri.ext #ID')` to chain as such:

`$("#example").load('./uri.ext #ID1').load('./uri.ext #ID2').load('./uri.ext #ID3')`

Which of course would be useful if we had a template file of DIVs or something to dynamically build a page and not store the HTML in a string variable or something along those lines... plus, we could keep several of these in one file.

Ideally I would like to nest things as such with that command:

```
<div id="example">
    <div id="ID1">
        <div id="ID2">
            <div id="ID3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problems I'm getting are two-fold. First, the `async : true` property of the request causes the next request to fire and the placement doesn't preform as intended. I had then attempted to run nested $("#example").load('./uri.ext #ID1').ajaxCompletes(function () {/*next .load() in sequence*/})` which ended up in a recursive trap that didn't end and kept sending requests for those files.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish what I'm after with a syntax/method like I had attempted? Also, if this isn't a problem and just a misunderstanding on my part of jQuery's chaining, an explanation I would be very thankful for any explanation into that.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with this. If you are just nesting a bunch of empty divs you might as well just pass in an array with ajax and do some .append() calls

Comment: @dave  the divs are examples of nesting, I'm not trying to nest a bunch of empty divs. The divs could be a table, or contain an input form, or text paragraphs... In concept, I would have a template.html file where I'm requesting these elements from, instead of something like `var str='<div id="ID3">Lorem Ipsum </div>'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to nest them in the callback functions to achieve this:

```
$('#example').load('./uri.ext #ID1', function() {
  $('#ID1').load('./uri.ext #ID2', function() {
    $('#ID2').load('./uri.ext #ID3', function() {
      // load successful
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT** for **ES6** standards:

```
 $('#example').load('./uri.ext #ID1', () => {
      $('#ID1').load('./uri.ext #ID2', () => {
        $('#ID2').load('./uri.ext #ID3', () => {
          // load successful
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Any insights into why the other actions take place?

Comment: The way you had it set up before, all of your calls were getting bound to the $("#example") object. That is how chaining with jquery works, the target is always the same; it is us not updated to inherit whatever result you received from the previous.

Answer (score 0):

Upvoted the question and the answer.

I'm providing a slightly more elegant solution using a recursive call in case others want to build on it. Note that this doesn't directly answer the context of the original question. It's in the context of my own solution, but the idea is the same.

```
var App = App || {};

App.Quiz = (function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var _templates = [{ target: "#quiz_main_template", url: "/UserControls/Quiz/Quiz_Main.tmpl.htm" },
        { target: "#quiz_media_left_template", url: "/UserControls/Quiz/Quiz_Media_Left.tmpl.htm" },
        { target: "#quiz_media_right_template", url: "/UserControls/Quiz/Quiz_Media_Right.tmpl.htm" },
        { target: "#quiz_no_media_template", url: "/UserControls/Quiz/Quiz_No_Media.tmpl.htm" }]

    function loadTemplates(templates, callback) {
        if (templates.length) {
            var nextTemplate = templates.pop();
            $(nextTemplate.target).load(nextTemplate.url, loadTemplates(templates, callback));
        } else {
            callback.call();
        }
    }

    function init() {
        loadTemplates(_templates, function () { alert("Done!");})
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    App.Quiz.init();
});
```