# Chaining two jQuery .load() requests results in the second overwriting the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use .load() to load the first two `a` links from the div `.static-links` from the same URL. I'm looking at this answer [jQuery chaining .load() requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736098/jquery-chaining-load-requests) to chain .load().

This is the source html at `http://example.com/links/` that contains the first two links I'm trying to load with `.load()`:

```
<div class="static-links">
<a href="http://example.com/">test 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/link2/">test 2</a>
<a href="http://example.com/link3/">test 3</a>
</div>
```

But with this jQuery, I don't get two links displayed in the div `.showlinks`:

```
$('.showlinks').load('http://example.com/links/ .static-links a:first', function () {
$('.showlinks').load('http://example.com/links/ .static-links a:nth-of-type(2)', function () {

$('.showlinks').prepend('<div class="read-unread">Unread</div>');
$('.showlinks a').visited('visited-link');
$('.showlinks a.visited-link').prev().addClass('read');
$('.showlinks a.visited-link').prev().text('Read');

});
});
```

I do see the first link flash as it loads in `<div class="showlinks"></div>` on my page, and then the second link is displayed over top of that. So I need both links to be displayed, one after another.

This is complicated by the fact that I'm using a jQuery function called jquery.visited.js https://github.com/ardouglass/jquery-visited/blob/master/src/visited.js . And I'm prepending a div. But, when not chaining the two .load requests, jquery.visited.js works fine with a single .load().

How can I correctly chain two .load() functions? Do I need a different callback? And how can the `prepend` work for each link, too?

**Edit 5/28/18:**

Using charlietfl's answer, this

```
var $showlinks = $('.showlinks')
// load first showlinks element
$showlinks.eq(0).load('http://example.com/links/ .static-links a:first', function() {
  // load second showlinks element
  $showlinks.eq(1).load('http://example.com/links/ .static-links a:nth-of-type(2)', function() {
  });
});
```

loads the first link `a:first`, but not `a:nth-of-type(2)`, resulting in:

```
<div class="showlinks">
<a href="http://example.com">test 1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.showlinks')` selects all of that class in page. So what you are doing is loading all of that class with same content in first `load()` then replacing all content in that class with second `load()`

Can use `eq()` to target specific ones by index

```
var $showlinks = $('.showlinks')
// load first showlinks element
$showlinks.eq(0).load('http://example.com/links/ .static-links a:first', function() {
  // load second showlinks element
  $showlinks.eq(1).load('http://example.com/culture/ .static-links a:nth-of-type(2)', function() {

    // do stuff to both
    $showlinks.prepend('<div class="read-unread">Unread</div>');
    $showlinks.visited('visited-link');
    $showlinks.prev().addClass('read');
    $showlinks.prev().text('Read');

  });
});
```

---

Another way to do this in parallel rather than nested calls is to use `$.get()` instead of `load()` and parse the responses yourself.

Then use `$.when` to run when both requests have completed

```
var $showlinks = $('.showlinks');
var baseUrl = 'http://example.com/';
var loadMeta= [
   {path: 'links', selector: '.static-links a:first'},
   {path: 'culture', selector: '.static-links a:nth-of-type(2)'}
];

function loadData(index){
   var opts = loadMeta[index];
   // return the $.ajax promise for `$.when()` to use below
   return $.get(baseUrl  + opts.path).then(function(data){
      $showlinks.eq(index).html( $(data).find(opts.selector) );
   })
}

// both requests get made right away
var req1 = loadData(0);
var req2 = loadData(1);

// runs after both requests have completed
$.when(req1, req2).then(function(){
           // do stuff to both
        $showlinks.prepend('<div class="read-unread">Unread</div>');
        $showlinks.visited('visited-link');
        $showlinks.prev().addClass('read');
        $showlinks.prev().text('Read');
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I see these better ways of doing it, but both examples only show the a:first link in .showlinks, with no console errors. Though the second example does prepend the .read-unread div. And I'm using $(document).ready(function()

Comment: Hard to help on what to display since not sure what remote html looks like or what you expect. I only copied the same selectors you had in question

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, I edited my question and added more details.

Comment: Can't really help without seeing the html that is being loaded. The problem is probably due to the selector used

Comment: I added the resulting html; it is a mystery  to me why it doesn't work; your code appears correct.

Comment: But the result is not what's needed...it's the source that is

Comment: The source html for the question is in the div `static-links`; the loaded output goes to the div `showlinks`.

Comment: OK...maybe I misunderstood where you are putting these. Is there more than one `.showlinks`? My code assumes so and would put second link from load in second `.showlinks`

Comment: Ah, OK. That works now! I need to add  a .showlinks for each link to be displayed. It's just different; I expected one .showlinks div to list all links. But that works fine and makes the markup more evident.

Comment: You can do it in one....but load() replaces all content so need $.get for at least one if do that and use `append()`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks!